# Why couldn’t dark matter be from advanced technologies?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, dark-matter

(Coming from a layman)

Why couldn’t dark matter be the consequence of advanced technology?

For many reasons I can imagine that the game theory for intelligent life is to eventually hide/ camouflage themselves. But in doing so they couldn’t erase gravitational evidence of their existence. Therefore hiding as dark matter.

The distribution of dark matter would probably rule this out but looking into it, at least to my understating, its not uniform which perhaps supports the idea.

What are the main reasons that make this very unlikely/ impossible?

Comment: As you learn quickly in science, very little is literally impossible. But once you start getting so speculative, there's not much you can say besides "well, that's a possibility..."

Comment: This falls into the category science fiction.

Comment: This site is for questions about mainstream physics, and personal theories are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @G.Smith http://cosmos.nautil.us/feature/55/is-physical-law-an-alien-intelligence and https://phys.org/news/2018-04-cosmic-gorilla-effect-aliens.html

Comment: I agree this question is off topic.  It is an inspiring question though because I hadn’t considered it before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In science, ideas are not valuable because they can't be proven wrong. Ideas are supposed to explain phenomena. Dark matter could be a product of advanced technologies and the point is not if it's unlikely or not but if this idea can explain what is observed.

So of course the world should take this idea seriously IF you also describe how this kind of dark matter would behave and how it would interact with the visible matter. If your description fits observational data and follows the laws of physics, great!

So, scientifically speaking, the question is not "Why couldn’t dark matter be from advanced technologies?" but instead "how could dark matter be from advanced technologies?". If you can answer that question based on facts, your idea is as good as any other.

Comment: In philosophical jargon, this is called falsifiability, and was promoted by Karl Popper, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper

Comment: I personally will never be able to answer that. I was just wondering if any experiment or data we have on dark matter today disapproves it could be artificial. As we are finding out what dark matter isn’t or can’t be.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, science tends to prefer simple explanations over complicated ones.  In the theory that you propose, why not suggest that everything in the observable universe was created by advanced technology.  We can't prove that it wasn't.  But science doesn't have to disprove every possible theory that someone has.  Existing scientific theory is the result of hundreds (or thousands) of years of research and probably billions of hours of scientific research.  In order for a theory to be viable it needs to do a better job explaining things than the existing theories in order for it to be given serious consideration.